# Pattern match(es) are non-exaustive -- How come my "otherwise" in the final guard fails to deal with an empty list?

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to match this pattern. MessageType is a type that I've created. This function takes in a string, and then depending on the first character of that string, it outputs a MessageType. Whenever I compile though, I get a warning saying:

```
 Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘parseMessage’: Patterns not matched: []
```

Here's my code:

```
parseMessage :: String -> MessageType
parseMessage (x:_)
  | x == 'I'      = Info
  | x == 'W'      = Warning
  | otherwise     = Error 1
```

How is it that my pattern matches aren't exhaustive? Wouldn't the `otherwise` guard catch anything else? I don't see how my function fails to catch all strings.

When I write the function like this, I do not get the warning.

```
parseMessage []     = error "Empty String"
parseMessage (x:_) = if x == 'I'
                        then Info
                        else if x == 'W'
                        then Warning
                        else Error 1
```

I rewrote my function this way because I saw that the warning says "Patterns not matched: []", so I explicitly handled it. But why is it that in the first version of my function, it says that the pattern is not handled. How does `otherwise` not catch everything besides the first two guards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guards are specific to a single pattern case in a function’s definition, so when you write this:

```
parseMessage (x:_)
  | x == 'I'      = Info
  | x == 'W'      = Warning
  | otherwise     = Error 1
```

…your guards won’t even be consulted if you run `parseMessage ""`. The `(x:_)` pattern would fail, so all of its guards are ignored. This needs to be the case in order for `x` to be bound within the guard conditions.

To fix this, you just need to add a case that handles the empty string:

```
parseMessage :: String -> MessageType
parseMessage ""   = Error 1
parseMessage (x:_)
  | x == 'I'      = Info
  | x == 'W'      = Warning
  | otherwise     = Error 1
```

Now you’ve handled all possible cases.

Comment: I'd get rid of the `otherwise` clause, and add `parseMessage _ = Error 1` at the end.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. An empty string wouldn't be caught by the guards because of the initial pattern that I set up to check the first element of a list.

Answer (score 8):

Why not write directly...

```
parseMessage ('I':_) = Info
parseMessage ('W':_) = Warning
parseMessage _       = Error 1
```